# Putting a resized image into media library with wp_get_image_editor(

Tags: plugin-development, images

I'm using `wp_get_image_editor()` to resize and save an image that is being uploaded to the Media Library.

```
$image = wp_get_image_editor( $newattachment_url );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $image ) ) {
        $image->rotate( 0 );
        $image->resize( 300, 300, false );
        $image->save('resizedimage.jpg');
    }
```

This is working fine however it is saving to the root of WordPress. How can I instead upload this file to the media library? I want to have the orignal image and the resized image in the media library.

`$newattachment_url` is the URL of the orignally uploaded image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `generate_filename` method of the [image editor class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Image_Editor). Like this:

```
$filename = $img->generate_filename( 'resized', ABSPATH.'wp-content/uploads/resized-images/');
$image->save($filename);
```

This will save the image, renamed `originalname-resized`, in the `resized-images` directory of the upload folder. This does not mean WordPress knows it is there. That depends on the context in which you are calling `wp_get_image_editor()`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up using `media_sideload_image()` to copy the resized image in the WP root to the media library and then using PHP's `unlink()` to remove the resized image in the root.